# Conditional style for rows in html tables

Tags: html, css, tr

I have a table in html which gets the data from a SQL query in PY. One of the columns in my SQL table is type (tp). I want the html table to show one color for each row of the same type and another for opposite. It´s a financial diary so when you input expenses SQL save that info. I want the table to show the history and expenses rows in red and incomes rows in green. Here it´s my PY and HTML code. Please help I´m lost

```
@app.route("/history")
@login_required
def history():
    """Show history of inputs"""

    inputs = db.execute("""
                SELECT amount, category, tp, transacted
                FROM inputs
                WHERE user_id = :user_id
                ORDER BY transacted ASC
                """, user_id=session["user_id"])

    return render_template("history.html", inputs=inputs)
```

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    History
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Transacted</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for input in inputs %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{input["tp"]}}</td>
                <td>{{input["amount"]}}</td>
                <td>{{input["category"]}}</td>
                <td>{{input["transacted"]}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check whether below code will work.
Define "red" and "green" css classes in your css file.

```
        <tbody>
            {% for input in inputs %}
            <tr>
                {% if input["tp"] == 'expense' %}
                    <td class="red">{{input["tp"]}}</td>
                    <td class="red">{{input["amount"]}}</td>
                    <td class="red">{{input["category"]}}</td>
                    <td class="red">{{input["transacted"]}}</td>
                {% else %}
                    <td class="green">{{input["tp"]}}</td>
                    <td class="green">{{input["amount"]}}</td>
                    <td class="green">{{input["category"]}}</td>
                    <td class="green">{{input["transacted"]}}</td>
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
```